# Javascript реализация стрелок в input number - The specified value "NaN" is not a valid number

Tags: javascript

У меня есть корзина товаров, в которой может быть множество различных сущностей. И я пытаюсь реализовать изменения кол-во товара с помощью `input` - `number` без стрелок, а с дополнительными кнопками `+/-`. И при нажатии этих кнопок у меня выводится ошибка `The specified value "NaN" is not a valid number` и я не догадываюсь почему. Я знаю что мог бы использовать `идентификаторы` и с легкостью сделать задуманное. Но в моем случае мне нужно использовать `querySelectorAll`. Помогите мне пожалуйста подправить данный код. `quantity-arrow-minus` уменьшает значение поля, а `quantity-arrow-plus` увеличивает.

```
<form action="{% url 'cart:cart_update' %}" method="GET">
    <button type="button" class="quantity-arrow-minus">-</button>
    <input type="number" class="update_cart" value="{{item.quantity}}">
    <button type="button" class="quantity-arrow-plus">+</button>
</form>
```

```
var minus = document.querySelectorAll('.quantity-arrow-minus');
var update_cart = document.querySelectorAll('.update_cart');
var plus = document.querySelectorAll('.quantity-arrow-plus');

minus.forEach(function(node) {
    node.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        update_cart.forEach(function(element) {
            element.value = parseInt(update_cart.value - 1);
        });
    });
});

plus.forEach(function(node) {
    node.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        update_cart.forEach(function(element) {
            element.value = parseInt(update_cart.value) + 1;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Зачем вам "document.querySelectorAll", если у вас кнопок+ и - только по одной?

Comment: @ВладиславЖидко, потому что на странице множество товаров и у каждого такая форма.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var minus = document.querySelectorAll('.quantity-arrow-minus');
var update_cart = document.querySelectorAll('.update_cart');
var plus = document.querySelectorAll('.quantity-arrow-plus');

minus.forEach(node => {
  node.addEventListener('click', () => {
    update_cart.forEach(element => {
      element.value = parseInt(+element.value - 1);
    });
  });
});

plus.forEach(node => {
  node.addEventListener('click', () => {
    update_cart.forEach(element => {
      element.value = parseInt(+element.value + 1);
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<form action="{% url 'cart:cart_update' %}" method="GET">
  <button type="button" class="quantity-arrow-minus">-</button>
  <input type="number" class="update_cart" value="{{item.quantity}}">
  <button type="button" class="quantity-arrow-plus">+</button>
</form>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вместо выделенных элементов надо было написать "element" :)

**UP**

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
  var target = event.target;
  if (target.tagName != 'BUTTON') return;

  if (target.classList.contains('quantity-arrow-minus')) {
    target.parentNode.querySelector('input').value = parseInt(+target.parentNode.querySelector('input').value - 1);
  }

  if (target.classList.contains('quantity-arrow-plus')) {
    target.parentNode.querySelector('input').value = parseInt(+target.parentNode.querySelector('input').value + 1);
  }
})
```

```html
<form action="{% url 'cart:cart_update' %}" method="GET">
  <button type="button" class="quantity-arrow-minus">-</button>
  <input type="number" class="update_cart" value="{{item.quantity}}">
  <button type="button" class="quantity-arrow-plus">+</button>
</form>
<form action="{% url 'cart:cart_update' %}" method="GET">
  <button type="button" class="quantity-arrow-minus">-</button>
  <input type="number" class="update_cart" value="{{item.quantity}}">
  <button type="button" class="quantity-arrow-plus">+</button>
</form>
<form action="{% url 'cart:cart_update' %}" method="GET">
  <button type="button" class="quantity-arrow-minus">-</button>
  <input type="number" class="update_cart" value="{{item.quantity}}">
  <button type="button" class="quantity-arrow-plus">+</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Не будет работать корректно, даже если поменять.

Comment: @Рустам Гимранов, я лишь изменил его код таким образом, чтобы не было ошибки ) Его вопрос был в этом

Comment: @Рустам Гимранов, ну вы же не знаете сколько у него форм и каким образом он хочет их изменять? Может он хочет, чтобы при нажатии на любую из кнопок плюса или минуса выводилось одинаковое зрачение сразу во всех инпутах?

Comment: @Рустам Гимранов, поправил с учётом ваших замечаний